# java library for computing of derivatives and integrals

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, shared-libraries

I want to develop a small application in JAVA, for personal use, that solves the derivatives and integrals. Can you tell me some good library to do this, and some example?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

[Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) contains the ability to integrate using different methods - see [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/analysis.html), section 4.5. The example [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/commons-math/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/math/analysis/integration/TrapezoidIntegratorTest.java.shtml) shows you how to use the `TrapezoidIntegrator`, the others work pretty much in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

[SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420265/do-calculus-in-java)

[Library reference](http://code.google.com/p/javacalculus/) hosted on google code.You can also use JLink with Mathematica to send your calculations part to mathematica and get appropriate results back.